# newbie thing with run(), but cant find answer. (Applet)

Tags: java, applet

Okay, so I have a simple Mario applet that does nothing atm. I haven't done something wrong (says the nonexistence error report) but it still doesnt work. What I mean by that is nothing inside the

```
  public void run() {
etc
    }
```

takes place. Even in while (true).

Heres a sample of what doesnt work (took out the bigger parts that are really just added on.)

```
public class Main extends Applet implements Runnable {

 //BLAHBLAHBLAH STUFF THAT HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH THE PROBLEM

public void run (){
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    while(true){
        xPos += xSpeed;
        yPos ++;

        try{
            Thread.sleep (20);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        } 

    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    } 

}

    //MORE UNIMPORTANT STUFF

    }
```

start() method

```
public void start() {

    Thread th = new Thread();
    th.start();

    Mario.xSpeed = 1;
    Mario.ySpeed = 1;
    Mario.radius = 25;
    Mario.xPos = 0;
    Mario.yPos = 125;

}
```

Comment: Yeah. Riiiight before the run in my code.

Comment: It could help if you showed some of that. If some piece of code isn't being executed, the problem usually lies where that code is called and not in that piece of code itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
Thread th = new Thread();
```

The problem is with this line. You need to pass the class (i.e. `this`) as an argument to the constructor.

Comment: I just found the answer :) I couldnt post it as an answer because of a    new user posting restriction. It needed to have

(this) 

as a parameter for Thread()

Comment: @JavaNewbie So what howardh said is the correct answer, please mark it as the correct answer